# How do I stop call recording for sensitive information In Amazon Connect

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-connect

I am working on AWS's Amazon Connect. I am creating a contact flow in which I need to store call recordings. So I am using Enable Call Recording component of Contact Flow and its working fine.

Now, suppose contact flow is taking some sensitive information such as Credit card details, in this case I need to stop call recording and then again start it once user done with sensitive information. How can I do this?

Thanks,
Gans

Answer (score 1):

You can disable recording in the contact flow by using the set recording behavior block, the same way you initially enabled it. This can be enabled or disabled as many times as needed during the contact flow itself, prior to routing the call to an agent. If you need to disable the recording after the call has already been routed at an agent, you would use a quick connect to send the caller back to a contact flow that set the recording behavior to disabled and use LEX or DTMF to capture the sensitive information before setting the recording back to an enabled state and reconnecting the caller to the agent (agent is placed on hold by using the quick connect in this situation).

Comment: @ganeshw Please accept the answer so other can more easily see that this question has an answer. Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible to transfer a call to a contact flow that disables call recording so the agent and customer can have a sensitive conversation? So far I have been unable to turn call recording off using the set block. After reading AWS documentation it seems this may only be possible by putting the agent on hold (for the customer to enter information through LEX/DTMF) - preventing the customer from having that conversation.

Comment: Link to the AWS blog on how to set this up
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/disable-recording-amazon-connect/

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the above approach is that it won't work well if you want the same agent to handle the call.  The transfer to Quick Connect will put the call on hold on the original leg while reattempting to connect back to the same agent and unless the agent quickly clicks on the "swap" button on CCP the call will be dropped.

You could transfer back to another queue with recording off and the same agent pool, but this would mean the customer may have to wait again for the call to be connected.

A better solution would be an Interactive prompt with an option to disable recording and the start of the contact flow.  The timeout could be set to continue with recording enabled so if nothing is pressed the call continues with recording on.

Answer (score 0):

Routing to the last agent is still possible with temp table data store in DynamoDB. The agent have to be blocked to get calls routed from the queue until the contact re-arrives or the call will be placed in the personal (invisible) queue of the agent.

Answer (score 0):

Use APIs that enable you to start, stop, pause, and resume call recording.
The call recording APIs are available in all AWS regions where Amazon Connect is offered. There is no charge to use these APIs. https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/07/amazon-connect-adds-call-recording-apis/